# PostgreSQL select record with multiple condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I am trying to select the record but not getting the record I wanted. here is my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5296a/1

so when I selects the record using below query

```
select title from post where (id>3 and author_id=3) or id>3 limit 1
```

it gives me result with the title `DDDDD`. it should give me `GGGGGGGG`.

I wanted to check if there is any record with `author_id=3` and greater than the post `id=3` if not then just get the any post id greater than 3.

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to check if there is any record with author_id=3 and greater than the post id=3 if not then just get the any post id greater than 3.

From what you describe, you want:

```
select title
from post 
where id > 3
order by (author_id = 3) desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a24cf97806a1cf078f23b3864e119866) is a db<>fiddle.  This filters all the rows so there is just `id > 3`.  The `order by` puts any rows with `author_id = 3` first, so the `limit` would return that one.

Your version just returns an arbitrary row that matches the `where` condition -- and that condition is equivalent to `where id > 3`.  The `where` conditions don't provide any sort of "preference".  They just specify whether or not a given row is in the result set.